APD product in local calling APDEditionService
We created a product in APD (advanced product designer) in cloud and finalized in local by syncing it with Cloud environment. PC developer local is calling the APD service everytime we create a new submission.
Here are the steps:
Imported mindmap in apd
updated our local to sync with Cloud APD by updating config properties etc.
Finalized the product in local by generating the artifacts.
The product is installed in our local.
When we create a new submission, PC is calling APD service to retrieve product and sync. We expect local developer machine to not have dependency on remote service for creating a new submission using finalized product. Is that the expected behavior?

When using the APD app to initially create your product (as opposed to the Product Management UI in PolicyCenter), this the expected behavior. This requires the refreshing of a Dev token every hour, as I'm sure you've discovered.
